# Content updated on Preview but not after Published?

Tags: sitecore

When I preview the content I have updated, it works fine. But after I published it, the site doesn't reflect the changes on other browsers and computer. What's the problem?

If I login to the admin area on a browser I can see the changes on the live site, but not on browsers I didn't login.

Comment: maby cache? the Sitecore cache needs to flush on publish, see the publish:end event or try /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx to see and flush your cache.

Comment: Do you have any workflow assigned to your items? And when you publish a single item, do you see "Item updated" or "Item skipped"?

Comment: Try to check updated item in Web DB.